# Chrome Extensions & JS Injection Issue - Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I inspected the page, script is injected as expected. But in the console I get **Denying load of chrome-extension://lkklhmfekbnfjhmcapngedajgkfbmapm/lib/codemirror.js. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.**

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name":"test",
"description":"Test description",
"version":"1.0",

"manifest_version": 2   ,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["file:///*test*"],  
        "js": ["test.js"]
    }
  ],
"web_accessible_resources": ["lib/codemirror.js"]
}
```

**test.js**

```
var srcArray = ["lib/codemirror.js"];                   

function AddScript(value)
{
    var s = document.createElement("SCRIPT")
    s.src = chrome.extension.getURL(value);
    s.onload = function() {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    };
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);       
}
srcArray.forEach(AddScript);
```

[image]

I cannot figure out what may be causing the issue. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if you made a typo, but it should be `manifest.json`, not `manifest.js`.

Comment: Yes, this is a typo. I have now edited the question. Thanks

Comment: @LukeG: Your code is working perfectly, are you referring to any other js file or any `chrome API` inside `codemirror.js`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but if you want to insert some scripts to some page, you can use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) API. That is good way, and you don't care about web_accessible_resources